# JavaScript execution function function after element arrival using arrive.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension and I have the following files. 
But the h1-title is not getting updated when I open https://example.com/ 
What am I missing here?

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Print Hello",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons": {
        "48": "images/icon-48.png"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "48": "images/icon-48.png"
        },
        "default_title": "Print Hello"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://example.com/"],
            "js": ["./scripts/arrive.js", "./scripts/print_hello.js"]
        }
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "https://example.com/"
    ]
}
```

print_hello.js

```
function print_hello() {
    document.querySelector("div h1").innerText = "Hello!"
}

document.arrive("div h1", function(newElem) {
    /* I need to wait for some element to appear */
    print_hello()
})
```

arrive.js from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uzairfarooq/arrive/master/minified/arrive.min.js

Comment: Your scripts run after the page is loaded, so you don't need arrive.js, you can simply use document.querySelector('h1')